# Unitary transformation to non-negative matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nonnegative-matrices

I am looking to perform a unitary transformation $U$ on a matrix $S$ such that
\begin{equation}
Q = USU^\dagger
\end{equation}
is an element-wise non-negative matrix.

I would like to know whether there is a constructive procedure for $U$, and what properties $S$ must have for such a transformation to be possible. For instance, I know that if $\operatorname{Tr}(S)<0$, then such a transformation does not exist.

I am interested in two particular cases:

(a) when $S$ is symmetric and unitary,

(b) when $S$ is diagonal (but non-negative).

Note: I have so far figured out that if $S$ is symmetric, unitary and has $\operatorname{Tr}(S)=0$, then $Q$ must be a complete permutation matrix. But even in this case, is there a way to find whether $Q$ exists or not or how to find it.